# Struct containing pointers to other structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Im trying to make a struct that holds several points to structs because i got a program that reads an img file, and depending on wheter this file is 16, 24 or 32 bit i want to treat it as such. The problem occurs when i try to make my pixelpointer point to one of the other structs ("incompatible types when assigning to type 'Pixel' from type 'Pixel24'"). I realy dont know how to make this work, so i really need some help on it.

I also want to check for a specific file extension when i open the file and i only want to process it if it's the correct file extension, but i have no clue as how to do that.

```
typedef struct pixel16 {
    uint8_t R, G, B;
}__attribute__((packed)) Pixel16;

typedef struct pixel24 {
    uint8_t R, G, B;
}__attribute__((packed)) Pixel24;

typedef struct pixel32 {
    uint8_t R, G, B, A;
}__attribute__((packed)) Pixel32;


typedef struct pixel{
    Pixel16 pixel16;
    Pixel24 pixel24;
    Pixel32 pixel32;
}__attribute__((packed)) Pixel;

typedef struct file{
    Header *imageHeader;
    Pixel *imageData;
}File

void something(File file){
   Pixel *pixelptr;

    if(file->imageHeader.pixelDepth == 16)
        *pixelptr = file->imageData->pixel16;
    else if(file->imageHeader.pixelDepth == 24)
        *pixelptr = file->imageData->pixel24;
    else
        *pixelptr = file->imageData->pixel32;
}
```

Comment: Updated my code a bit, had forgotten to add the struct File i use to collect the imagadata and header info in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union:

```
typedef struct {
    int depth;
    union {
        Pixel16 p16;
        Pixel24 p24;
        Pixel32 p32;
    } data;
} Pixel;

if (pixel.depth == 16)
    pixel.data.p16 = ...;
else if (pixel.depth == 24)
    pixel.data.p24 = ...;
else if (pixel.depth == 32)
    pixel.data.p32 = ...;
```

A union lets you access any one of its field, while only taking up the storage for the largest member.

As for the extension part, you can use `strrpbrk()` to scan the string from the end until the first dot or directory separator.

```
ext = strrpbrk(path, "./");

if (!ext || *ext != '.')
    ; /* No extension found. */

if (!strcmp(ext, ".png")
    ...
else if (!strcmp(ext, ".bmp")
    ...
else
    ... /* Unknown extension. */
```

Comment: I might just be an idiot here (never used union before), but i get "request for member 'data' in something nor a structure or union" when i try this. (although i dont see why as it clearly is a union im trying to reach)

Comment: @UserQuestion Sorry, my bad. The `data` (name of the field) should go at the end. I've corrected it in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mixture of unions and structs:

```
typedef struct pixel16 {
    uint8_t R, G, B;
}__attribute__((packed)) Pixel16;

typedef struct pixel24 {
     uint8_t R, G, B;
}__attribute__((packed)) Pixel24;

typedef struct pixel32 {
     uint8_t R, G, B, A;
}__attribute__((packed)) Pixel32;


typedef union pixel {
    Pixel16 pixel16;
    Pixel24 pixel24;
    Pixel32 pixel32;
} Pixel;

typedef struct file{
    Pixel *imageData;
}File
```

You would then use it with something like the following:

```
void something(File file){
Pixel *pixelptr;

    if(file->imageHeader.pixelDepth == 16)
        *pixelptr = file->imageData.pixel16;
    else if(file->imageHeader.pixelDepth == 24)
        *pixelptr = file->imageData.pixel24;
    else
        *pixelptr = file->imageData.pixel32;
}
```

Comment: To make it work (somewhat) i have to call:
*pixelptr = file->imageData->pixel16; (a . isnt working after imageData), but then i get a new error: "incompatible types when assigning to type Pixel from Type Pixel16" (im probably just being an idiot, but i cant make it work)

Comment: @UserQuestion You are trying to store `Pixel16` in a `Pixel`. The union lets you share the same storage with all the types, but when working with the data, you still need to access it with the correct type (which would be `Pixel16`). In my answer, the `depth` field denotes which union member you should be accessing once you have determined the pixel depth of the file.

Comment: Ah, of course. But does that not mean that i can not use a single pixelptr to do all the work later? I have to switch after what pixelptr that is used on everything i will do later?

Comment: @UserQuestion The pixel depth is probably stored in the `imageHeader` so rather than storing the pixel depth in each `Pixel` structure, you could just use the depth in the header to know which union member to access.

Comment: Scratch that last one, i understood it now. Thanks a lot for the patience :)